# Mosaico social media buttons

Tags: mosaico, social-media

Is it possible to change the social media button options in Mosaico templates? We'd like to be able to direct people towards our Telegram channel, but that isn't a default option.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what current version you are on but Telegram is definitely an option in Mosaico 3.2 (not sure when it was introduced)